# IE is not responding after loading an application on chrome its working fine

Tags: java, jsp

IE11 is not responding after loading my application on chrome its working fine.

What could be the reason?

Below is the few of the jsp content of `layout.jsp` file.

```
<%@ page language='java' contentType='text/html; charset=UTF-8'%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles" %>
<%@taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>
<%@include file="/WEB-INF/pages/themes.jsp"%>
<html>
    <head>
        <META content="IE=5" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
```

Comment: give space between `@ taglib and include`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

instead of

```
<META content="IE=5" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
```

and also give space between `@ and include` also `@ and taglib`